# connect to wlan0, and eth0 as safeguard in etc/network/interfaces

Tags: networking, wireless, internet, ethernet

I am currently running rpis headless that send data over ethernet to a server that is also connected to the router through ethernet.

Using a usb wifi adapter and keeping the same IP address, i would like the data to be sent over wifi, but still have the ethernet connection active in case the connection is lost. Throughout the experiment, data transmission will alternate between wifi and ethernet. Which I plan to do by commenting out the `wlan0` code in the `etc/network/interfaces` file.

Here is what my `/etc/network/interfaces` file looks like (ethernet only):
    # lo
    auto lo
    iface lo inet loopback

```
#eth0
auto lo eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

would this try to connect to wlan0, then if it fails connect to eth0? :

```
#lo
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# wlan0
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
  wpa-ssid MacRobotics
  wpa-psk password

# eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

i am having trouble understanding the ifup and ifdown syntax, but think that it might be required to switch from wlan0 to eht0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have the same IP, but you can just have both interfaces active at once and set up a script to try to determine if the wireless connection is up, then use that.  Then if it's not up, default to eth0.

But if you've already got a cable run. why use wifi at all?  Ethernet is much faster/more reliable/all around better than USB wifi...

Comment: pardon my lack of correct terminology, but my goal is to increase the electromagnetic radiation emitted from the router through flooding the network. The rPis send data ~15 times a minute, and have additionally created a daemon to ping the server to accomplish this further.

Comment: With regard to your adding a script idea, doesn't the code I posted try to connect over wifi, then default to ethernet?

Comment: why more RF radiation?

Comment: There are other ways to do that...

Comment: It is for my MSc research regarding EMF and honeybees. i am  interested in talking to you more about this.

Comment: You want to read this: http://www.theregister.co.uk/2015/06/09/power_your_temperature_sensor_with_this_bonkers_router_hack/

Comment: I'm subscribed to a magazine, 'QST', which released an article similar to this.  You will need to change the router's firmware in order to do this, but you will not need to do anything client side.  In fact, you should be able to just take the modded router, plug it in, and it should work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26355/discussion-between-evan-and-daniel).